# how to reduce image file size in python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

So I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607468/how-to-reduce-the-image-file-size-using-pil) and got the following code from it:

```
import Image, ImageFile  
pic = pic/goes/here.jpg
im = Image.open(pic)
width, height = im.size
if width > 1000 or height > 1000:
    width = width*.7
    height = height*.7
im = im.resize((int(math.floor(width)), int(math.floor(height))), Image.ANTIALIAS)
try:
    im.save(pic,optimize=True,quality=80)
except IOError:
    ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = width * height
    im.save(pic,optimize=True,quality=80)
```

The last bit at the end came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788398/how-to-save-progressive-jpeg-using-python-pil-1-1-7) as I noticed PIL just kind of gave up when the file exceeded around 1500~ px in size (I have no clue why?)

The problem is that when I run this code with a roughly 2500x1600 image PIL either gives me an image thats the same size (1.2MB) or an empty file with 0 MB. I once even got a file that was bigger!?!? (1.38MB)

So what am I doing wrong? I just want to optimize the image to as small of a file size without losing about 80% quality.

Also any other ways to reduce the file size in python? Thanks!!

Comment: After resetting the `ImageFile.MAXBLOCK` after an `IOError` you need to do another `im.save()` with it in effect.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; `pic` is not set anywhere.

Comment: Sorry! Didnt notice that I took this bit out of a function, its fixed now @martineau thanks! Im going to do a few more tests and that might be the issue

Comment: You may not be enlarging `MAXBLOCK` enough. Recode the `im.save()` in a loop that incrementally increases the value several times before giving up. The goal is to make it big enough to read the entire image in at once so it can be optimized properly.

Comment: How silly! Thanks its fixed, I just forgot to put the im.save after maxblock thank you martineau, you should make an answer so I can give you holiday karma. ;D

Comment: @bnynn: have you tried `Pillow` (`$ pip install pillow`)? [The bug might be fixed there](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/148)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the image file size using PIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607468/how-to-reduce-the-image-file-size-using-pil)

Answer (score 1):

I'm late here - but I noticed you have the quality set to 80.  The default is 75.  That could be the reason your file was larger.

Comment: lol only 4 years late nbd. I think wat I ended up doing was using another library to compress the image.

Comment: @bnynn Any idea which one?